Please take a look at my contract
The issues I am currently encountering are:
The user has already authorized the contract once, but when I process transactions in the backend, the user still gets prompted to authorize again.
The gas fee for the authorization that pops up is 5.x ETH. I am currently testing on MetaMask and the Sepolia testnet.
Sincere thanks to all of you.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract USDTManager {
    IERC20 public usdt;
   

    
    constructor() {
      usdt = IERC20(0x7169D38820dfd117C3FA1f22a697dBA58d90BA06); 
        
    }

  
    function approveUnlimitedUSDT() public {
        uint256 maxUint = type(uint256).max;
        require(usdt.approve(address(this), maxUint), "Approval failed"); 
    }


    function transferUSDTFromUser(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public {
     
        require(usdt.transferFrom(from, to, amount), "Transfer failed");
    }

 


    function getUSDTBalance(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return usdt.balanceOf(account);
    }
}


P.S. I am using HTML + Web3 for interaction.

Remove the approveUnlimitedUSDT() function. The user themselves should authorize through a front-end, allowing the USDTManager contract to spend on their behalf.
Here is a modified version of your smart contract that makes the interaction flow clearer:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}

contract USDTManager {
    IERC20 public usdt;

    constructor(address usdtAddress) {
        usdt = IERC20(usdtAddress); // Constructor takes the token address as an argument
    }

    // Transfers USDT from one user to another; must be approved by the 'from' address
    function transferUSDTFromUser(address from, address to, uint256 amount) public {
        // Ensure the contract is approved to transfer 'amount' tokens from 'from'
        require(usdt.transferFrom(from, to, amount), "Transfer failed");
    }

    // Get the USDT balance of an address
    function getUSDTBalance(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        return usdt.balanceOf(account);
    }
}


But my goal is, "once the user grants authorization, future transactions should not require the user to authorize again." After removing the feature, there will be no more "authorization" step.

The user should grant authorization through some frontend by calling approve method on the token contract with the USDTManager contract address as the spender. You can make this an infinite approval by using the max uint256 value as approved allowance, but it's not possible to approve a user's own tokens through USDTManager itself.

So, basically my contract is fine? But why, for such a simple contract, when I tried to transfer 500 USDT from wallet A to wallet B on the Sepolia testnet, I was charged 5 ETH? Is it due to high gas fees?

@Lin I think either you have a misconception of how approve works (completely understandable since I had it myself when I first learned Solidity) or I'm misunderstanding your intention with the code. The only address that can execute this function is the actual owner of the tokens to be spent. If you add a line to call approve in a smart contract, then that smart contract itself should be the owner of those tokens. You cannot write smart contract code to approve tokens to be spent from a user's wallet.
